# Missing space with Libertinus and LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, libertinus

I’m currently using the Libertinus fonts for both the main text and the mathematical content, and lualatex for compiling.
But I noticed that in certain constellations some (much needed) space seems to be missing, mostly to the right of certain letters.

This is most noticeable if these letters are in math mode, followed by a closing parenthesis which is in text mode.
Sometimes the letters clash right into the parenthesis.
The same problem happens when these letters are used as a subscript in math mode.
The problem is also noticeable with inline mathematics, although it depends on the letters how much.
(As an example, the spacing after `$f$` is quite unpleasant.)

[image]

These problems do not occur when the document is compiled with xelatex instead of lualatex.
With xelatex the output looks as follows:

[image]

This leads me to believe that this is a problem with the lua(la)tex compiler.
Is this is known problem?
If so, can it be solved or circumvented?

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\begin{document}

  \subsection*{Math module followed by a closing text parenthesis}
  $F$) $H$) $I$) $J$) $K$) $M$) $N$) $T$) $U$) $V$) $W$) $X$) $Y$) $Z$) $d$) $f$) $l$)
  \subsection*{Subscript followed by an opening math parenthesis}
  ${}_F($
  ${}_H($
  ${}_I($
  ${}_J($
  ${}_K($
  ${}_M($
  ${}_N($
  ${}_T($
  ${}_U($
  ${}_V($
  ${}_W($
  ${}_X($
  ${}_Y($
  ${}_Z($
  ${}_d($
  ${}_f($
  ${}_l($
  \subsection*{In text}
  Let $f$ have, let $F$ be, let $d$ be, let $U$ be, then $V$ has and $H$ fits $f$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is probably a problem in the font rather than in LuaTeX.  Also keep in mind that XeTeX just blatantly ignores font metrics and uses its own (which is better in the case of broken fonts but worse in the case where the font provides proper metrics).

Comment: The prpblem is known. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484667/change-bounding-box-of-math-glyphs-in-luatex/484673?r=SearchResults#484673

Comment: @HenriMenke it's more luatex than the font, although it's "by design"

Comment: @HenriMenke What font metrics are ignored by XeTeX, I don’t recall it ever being the case (except for using ascender and desecender for glyph height and depth, which have no definition in OpenType and the default is to use the bounding box like LuaTeX does).