# Garamond for both text and math

Tags: newtxmath, mathdesign, ebgaramond, garamond, garamondx

As far as I'm concerned, there are three main ways of producing documents using the Garamond typeface for both text and math, namely:

- Using the `mathdesign` package, which lets you use both URW Garamond and Adobe Garamond Pro.
- `newtxmath` package in combination with `garamondx`, which also uses URW Garamond.
- `garamond-math` package, which uses EB Garamond.

Is there any recommendation/best practice or is it just a matter of personal taste?

Can someone point out the main differences between using each method?

Answer (score 4):

I am not an expert - I just looked at the most obvious resource (CTAN).

### `mathdesign`

Was last updated in **2013** and the [manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathdesign) states:

> The package `mathdesign` replaces all the default mathematical fonts of
> TEX with a complete set of mathematical fonts, designed to be combined
> with a text font of your choice.

### `garamond-math`

Was last updated in **2019** and the [CTAN page](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/garamond-math) states:

> The font is best used with XeTeX and the `unicode-math` package. Other
> engines (e.g. LuaTEX; also: MS Word) are likely to produce
> unsatifactory spacings.
>
> This font is still under development, so do not expect it to be free
> of bugs. Any component might be updated at any time. Issues, bug
> reports, forks, and other contributions are welcome.

**I read this as "XeTeX only"?!**

### `newtx`

Was last updated in **2020** and seems to be very professional. The [manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/newtx) states:

> More recently, an option to provide math support for the `garamondx`
> text font package was added.

The CTAN page of [`garamondx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/garamondx) states:

> The package adds small caps, f-ligatures and old style figures to `URW GaramondNo8`. The package also provides a matching maths italic add-on
> for use with `newtxmath`.

### Conclusion

Without further investigation, I would choose `newtx`.

Update: See discussion in the comments of the answer.

---

### Update 2022-01-31

**garamond-math** is updated and the [CTAN site](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/garamond-math) states the following:

> Garamond-Math Ver. 2022-01-03
>
> Garamond-Math is an open type math font matching the [EB Garamond (Octavio Pardo)](https://github.com/octaviopardo/EBGaramond12/) and [EB Garamond (Georg Mayr-Duffner)](https://github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond). Many mathematical symbols are derived from other fonts
> (see below), others are made from scratch. The metric is generated
> with a python script.

Comment: Not quite. `newtx` is a clone of Times, so the text and math font won't really match (though the combination doesn't look too bad). I prefer (matter of taste) `garamond-math` with `EB-Garamond` in LuaTeX. In pdfTeX there's also `ebgaramond-maths` and `mathastext` that could help

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks for your comment. If the CTAN remark is correct, then garamond-math should be used with XeTeX only?!

Comment: The author of `garamond-math` optimised the font to be used with XeTeX, so it works best there. But in my (not too broad) experience it works pretty well with LuaTeX too. The only major problem I found was this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/484667/134574

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks for the update.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replies. After more reading I guess I'll stick to **EB Garamond** and `garamond-math` (as I see it it's a better option than `ebgaramond-maths`). I don't mind using only XeTeX for the time being

Answer (score 1):

The `newtx` package now has `ebgaramond` and matching math font and it works with `pdflatex`.  Very good looking and readable.  I am loading it with

```
\usepackage[
  vvarbb,
  amsthm,
  ebgaramond,
  frenchmath,
  smallerops]{newtx}
```

With some classes, like `tufte-handout`, it needs to be loaded as the following or the `stix` bb-fonts won't load (the `vvarbb` option to `newtx`)

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \usepackage[
  vvarbb,
  amsthm,
  ebgaramond,
  frenchmath,
  smallerops]{newtx}
  
}
```